# I have an error when I try to connect to PostgreSQL from Entity Framework

Tags: postgresql, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Entity Framework provider type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlServices,Npgsql.EntityFramework' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' could not be loaded.
Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.
See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'
```

If I add

```xml
<system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
          <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
          <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF"/>
      </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

in `app.config`, the following error appears:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'
ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.data.
```

My `app.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework,Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="User Id=postgres;Password=pass#123;Host=localhost;Database=db_clients;" providerName="Npgsql"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
          <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
          <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF"/>
      </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices,Npgsql.EntityFramework"></provider>
        </providers>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory,Npgsql"/>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I tried to add `<system.data>`, but it returned another error.

Comment: "Another error": please always copy and paste the complete error message. Also, you have a better chance to get a good answer if you present one problem, not three.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth to try and start with adjusting providers section.

From:

```
<providers>
   <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices,Npgsql.EntityFramework"></provider>
</providers>
```

To:

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
</providers>
```

Based on a similar problem other users have - [Postgresql and Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352203/postgresql-and-entity-framework)